# Portable convert excel to mysql

Tags: mysql, microsoft-excel, portable

Is there a portable windows (xp and above) software that can convert a excel file (xlsx, xls and ods) into mysql file (sql)?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321686

Comment: [http://www.excel2mysql.net/](http://www.excel2mysql.net/)

Comment: Should it be able to work offline? Are web-based applications OK?

Comment: Is any SQL structure OK? For instance inserting the whole file as a blob, or one table per tab, or tabs/rows/cells tables? Do you have any preferences for cell references in formulas?

Answer (score 2):

[image: sqlizer.io screenshot]

Try https://sqlizer.io (I work here) which converts Excel (xls and xlsx) files to SQL databases. It's free for small databases (under 5000 rows) then costs $15.

You have to tell it which worksheet and range you want to import and then it does a pretty decent job from there onwards.